# Search and get variables of a specific type and name from diferent classes instances

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I have a list of objects (diferent types) and I want to loop through it looking for variables called color of type Color to modify them.

Is there a way to do it without reflection? If not, what's the most efficient way to do with reflection? The list will have about 200+- objects and it should update every frame. Also, I cannot create a Super class like ColoredObjects or something because this classes are built-in and I cannot modify them.

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Comment: *"variables"* are they *fields*? *properties*? should we modify `public` only or `private` as well?

Comment: Do you know the types of all the objects you need to set the property for?

Comment: Yes, I am using Unity, I want to create multiple UI themes and change them by code. The variables can be fields or properties but all public. And no, I don't know the types, I have a list of objects of multiple types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list consists of `GameObjects`:

```
    Color colorToSet = Color.red;

    foreach (var item in objList)
    {
        foreach (Component component in item.GetComponents<Component>())
        {
            foreach (var property in component.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Color) && property.CanWrite)
                {
                    property.SetValue(component, colorToSet);
                }
            }

            foreach (var field in component.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                if (field.FieldType == typeof(Color))
                {
                    field.SetValue(component, colorToSet);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If it's a list of `Monobehaviour` scripts remove the `.GetComponents()` loop.